# Binding ng-click argument object keys to scope properties?

Tags: angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I'm trying to pass an object with variable keys to an ng-click method. In regular javascript you would just do this:

```
var x = "fork";
var obj = {};
obj[x] = "three points" //{ fork: "three points" }
```

Normally to send objects via ng-click you would set up an object literal as the argument.

```
//in controller
$scope.val = "red";
//in view
<button ng-click="click( { item: val} )"></button> 
//output is { item: "red" }
```

But what if you want the key of the argument's object to be bound to a scope property?

```
//in controller
$scope.key = 29845;
//in view
<button ng-click="click( { {{key}}: 456 } )"></button>
//should output { 29845: 456 }
```

Trying this results in a syntax error. However, you can use this same syntax in ui.bootstrap typeahead's `typeahead-on-select` method and it works... I have no idea why though.

```
<input type="text"     
       typeahead="i for i in data"
       typeahead-on-select="select( { {{i}}: 'something' } )"
       class="typeahead" />
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EfSvbP8fXBLoZhr8eWG5

How can you bind scope properties to object keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
<button ng-click="temp={};temp[key]=456;click(temp)"></button>
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/NfH3xNUXtBROiu9olHVE?p=preview.

Though it will add temp variable in the scope.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot you can include entire expressions in the ng-click directive, thanks